# EWS SearchFolder does not return values from body

Tags: exchangewebservices, officedev

I am trying to create a SearchFolder using the EWS API (managed or web service directly). I noticed that I if I create a `SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring` on the `ItemSchema.Body`, I do not get any conversations from it.

here is how I create my folder:

```
var folder = new SearchFolder(service)
{
    DisplayName = topic
};
var searchParameters = folder.SearchParameters;
searchParameters.SearchFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, topic, ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters);
searchParameters.RootFolderIds.Add(WellKnownFolderName.Root);
searchParameters.Traversal = SearchFolderTraversal.Deep;
folder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.SearchFolders);
```

Later, I try to get the conversations from this folder:

```
service.FindConversation(conversationView, folder.Id);
```

And this returns 0 conversations.
I made sure by sending two messages to my email account, the first with a special term only in the subject, and the second with the same term in the body. If I create a SearchFolder with a filter on the `ItemSchema.Subject`, I get the first conversation, but using the SearchFolder I created above, I do not get the expected result.

Are there some restrictions regarding the ContainsSubstring SearchFilter? I tried using NormalizedBody or TextBody, but then I got errors in the folder creation process. Is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Doing a search filter on the body will likely be problematic. This goes back to how potentially large properties like `Body` are handled in contents tables. A query string search would likely work better, but you can't use a query string to create a search folder.